# checking `aStr == null` in C++

Tags: c++

I dont understand why the following piece of code would give me a compile error:

```
string a = NULL:
if (a == NULL)        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< something is wrong with this line????
{ /* do something */ }
```

This gives :
`error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘a != 0l’`

Comment: Which part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a colon after the first NULL?  Did that error come from that code, or from some other code? You're not using !=, you're using ==.

Comment: `string a = NULL` is UB for `std::string`.

Comment: What's `aStr`?  What's `null`?  Why are you not showing us the actual code giving you that error?

Comment: Ok, here's the thing. I don't understand the reason for downvotes! I asked a question, because I really didn't understand why it was getting compile-error. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (a == NULL)` can't work since you are comparing a `std::string` with an Integer which is not possible. if you want to create an empty string and test for emptiness just do:

```
string a;
if (a.empty())
{ /* do something */ }
```

Comment: Would that NOT give you some error due to un-init variable OR throw NPE? (Sorry, I'm from a Java background)

Comment: @One Two Three: No, `string a;` calls the default constructor of `string` which initializes `a` as an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

`string` in C++ is not the same as the string in C.  You will need to compare a string with string as `a == string ("")`.

Comment: c++ std::string has overloaded operator== so the cast is not necessary.

Comment: `std::string` also implements [`empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty), so the entire `==` is not necessary.

Comment: Any if you did use == (which is ok for readability for some people), you only need `a == ""`

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at that, the colon at the end of the first line instead of a semicolon is definitely going to throw a wrench in there.  Not sure if that is it, but I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize to an empty string with double quotes, and check whether the string is empty.
Or is it a must for you to use NULL?

```
string a = "";
if (a == "")
{   /* dosomething */ }
```